# Finding paths in undirected graph with specific cost

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, dijkstra, depth-first-search, backtracking

Suppose we have undirected, weighted graph. Our task is to find all paths beetween two vertices (source and destination) which total cost equal = N.
I think it can be done with modified Dijkstra's algorithm combined with BFS or DFS, but I have no idea how implement such thing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Equal, or at most equal? If it is the former, the problem is NP-hard via reduction to the hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: Then your problem is NP-hard (NP-complete or even worse), and I can't seem to find a NP solution to _count_ the paths.

Comment: Note there can be up to `(n-2)!` solutions (complete graph, all edges equal in length, a hamiltonian path is desired), so enumeration will be slow as hell.

Comment: my goal isnt count the path, is to count the total path's value that be equel to N

Comment: You want to enumerate the paths whose length is `N`, right? There could be _many_ of them.

Comment: yes, this is my goal. (our graph has maximum 30 Vertex)
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a framework / library to create a graph data structure and to traverse it, you could do a backtracking depth-first search with an early return if you cross your resource constraint. In pseudo-code:

```
void DFS(Vertex current, Vertex goal, List<Vertex> path, int money_left) {
  // oops
  if (money_left < 0) 
     return;

  // avoid cycles
  if (contains(path, current)
     return;

  // got it!
  if (current == goal)) {
     if (money_left == 0)
         print(path);
     return;
  }

  // keep looking
  children = successors(current); // optionally sorted from low to high cost
  for(child: children)          
      DFS(child, add_path(path, child), money_left - cost(child));      
}
```

and you can then call it as `DFS(start, goal, List<Vertex>(empty), N)`

Comment: Shouldn't you only print if money_left == 0? Looks good otherwise

Comment: @Patashu tnx, updated. Without that clause, it would find all paths with `cost <= N`

Comment: It should still return if current == goal but money_left != 0, so it doesn't go on a pointless search past the goal

Comment: @Patashu good to see that in your time zone you are not almost asleep ;-) updated.